# Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string,object given in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

im trying to upload Excel data to database in php im getting warning error.

```
<?php
$datepub = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($conn,$Row[6]));
```

Comment: If `$conn` is a database connection, I'm going to have a propper laugh. Please just read http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Your question is not about MySQL nor MySQLi, so your tags are not correct. Your code sample is not reproducible, we haven't `$conn` nor `$Row`, we have to guess it. Please read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a typo since the OP simply didn't check the manual for the correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

Please check php manual.

```
int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )
```

You can not pass an object into it, it needs to be a date string like below.

```
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11.12.10"));
```

Comment: I think a link to the documentation in comment would be enough.
Once I'd answered a question like you with _only_ a reference to the documentation because there was not a real problem, and I'd been downvoted because answers like that are not good ones (because the question wasn't neither).